# php unset() what does it really do?

Tags: php

The PHP [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) states the following about the `unset()` language construct:

> destroys the specified variables.
>
> Unset a given variable

What does this really mean? Just destroy the variable content; empty out a variable and give it the value `null`? Or does it mean, wipe out the variable not just it's content but everything?

I wrote the following:

```
$a = "tom";

unset($a);

var_dump($a);
```

and got this:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: a in...
```

Comment: It is complicated what it does internally. All you need to know at this moment is that it destroys the reference (variable name) to a value, so the value becomes impossible to reach with the given variable name.

Comment: It removes its name from the local variable nametable, and deallocates the associated zval store.

Comment: I imagine once you remove the reference, PHP's internal garbage collector takes it from there. However, it also depends on what kind of variable you are unsetting, may it be a value in an associative array or a global reference, it doesn't necessarily destroy the variable completely.

Comment: @mario: if only ref counter is zero

Answer (score -1):

It destroys the content, and leaves the variable in an undefined state.

If you try to access the variable again after it's unset, and you have warnings disabled, you might be able to retrieve the value, but it's absolutely not guaranteed.

Comment: It's not entirely correct. It doesn't guarantee to destroy anything. `$a = 1; $b = $a; unset($a);` -- here the "content" is not "destroyed"

Comment: True, but most likely the garbage collector will reuse the memory for something else after some time, which will "destroy it". Not necessarily immediately.

Comment: "but most likely" --- well, no.

Comment: Well, in your example, the content is copied. So $a might not contain 1 after the garbage collector passes.

Comment: "Well, in your example, the content is copied" --- it's not. In my example there is a single zval with `1` value is allocated and 2 variables that refer to it.

Comment: @zerkms It indeed destroys the content. You did not pass the content by reference, hence it only removed the content of the first variable.

Comment: @Christian: it's not. Please google something on "copy on write" in php. Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ykcnzbj1ME is a really interesting video

Comment: @zerkms Actually, you're quite right there. Forgot the "copy on write" trick.

Comment: For all who are interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ykcnzbj1ME here at 40:00 Julian starts speaking on copy on write

Answer (score -4):

**One more example:**

A sample how to unset array elements from an array result coming from a mysql request. In this sample it is checking if a file exists and removes the row from the array if it not exists.

```
<?php
$db->set_query("select * from documents where document_in_user = 0"); //1 
$documents = $db->result_to_array($db->get_result()); //1

foreach ($documents as $key => $row) { //2

    $file     = "uploads/".rawurldecode($row['document_name']);

    if ( file_exists ( $file ) == FALSE ) {
         unset($documents[$key]);  //3
    } 
}

$documents = array_values($documents); // reindex the array (4)
?>
```

**Variables:**

```
mysql table = documents,
array = $documents
array key (index) = $key
array row (record sort of speak) = $row
```

**Explanation:**

**1.** it gets the array from the table (mysql)

**2.** foreach goes through the array $documents

**3.** unset if record does not exist

**4.** the `array_values($documents)` reindexes the `$documents array`, for otherwise you might end up in trouble when your  process will start expecting an array starting with key **($key)** **0 (zero)**.

Comment: I'm failing to see how `unset()` is being actively used & explaining how it actually works..